# Angular 7: ngClass takes only initial value

Tags: angular, ng-class

Consider the following example:

Template:

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngFor="let item of menu">
      <i [ngClass]="{'isActive': isActive(item)}"></i>
      ...
</div>
```

And in the component:

```
  public isActive(item: SideNavMainItem): boolean {
    return this.router.url.indexOf(item.url) !== -1;
  }
```

The problem is that `ngClass` works fine only for the first time, when the app has been initiated, but when I navigate through the links nothing is change: `isActive` was not added neither removed.

Comment: Try make your function isActive return true or false as string i mean 'true' or 'false'

Comment: Can you provide this scenario via stackblitz?

Comment: Log to the console what you are returning in isActive() method. Maybe for the first time it is returning what you are expecting but not other times. It's totally depends on what you are returning.

Comment: What is `item.url`?

Comment: Okay I'm really really sorry, but the problem was in incorrect router implementation, I'm using custom router service in my hybrid app, thanks for everyone

Comment: @LuninRoman how are you navigating is it using `routerLink` then just use `routerLinkActive="some-class"` for example   `<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="some-class">Bob</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<i [class.isActive]="isActive(item)"></i>
```

Comment: This basically does the same, though thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz